# overlap of data

Tags: list-manipulation, date-and-time

I have two individual Date lists as Date Objects:

```
List 1 = {1 Jan 1991 9 :00 , 3 Jan 1991 11:00 ..etc } 
List 2 ={ 7 Jan 1991 14:00, 9 Jan 1991 15:00 ..etc}
```

For any given date, example 5 Jan 1991 10:00 how can I check if this random date lies between corresponding elements in both lists i.e.,is  (5 Jan 1991 10:00) is in between (1 Jan 1991 9:00) and (7 Jan 1991 14:00) . If it is true , then it should give the corresponding dates between which it falls.

I tried to use for loop. but its taking a lot of time as the data is huge.Is there any efficient way to code this logic?

Comment: Are the two lists sorted by date and time and every element is newer than the previous element? If so then perhaps a binary search to find the index of date in the first list that is most recent to your random date and do a single subscript to get the corresponding date from the second list?

Comment: Hi @Bill...Thanks for reply...but every element is sorted  by date and time but some elements are same as the previous ones

Answer (score 3):

Let's build up samples for your lists first:

```
SeedRandom[42];
at = AbsoluteTime;
l = Transpose@RandomInteger[{0, 360}, {50, 2}];
{l1, l2} = Map[DateString@DatePlus[{1991, 1, 1}, #] &, l, {2}];
myDate = at@"7 Jan 1991";
```

And compare:

```
p = MapThread[Less[#1, myDate, #2] || Less[#2, myDate, #1] &, Map[at, {l1, l2}, {2}]]
(*
{False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, \
False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, \
False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, \
False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, \
False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, \
False}
*)
```

The intervals that contain the desired date are:

```
Pick[Transpose@{l1, l2}, p] // TableForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And the non-conformant intervals are:

```
Pick[Transpose@{l1, l2}, Not /@ p] // TableForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]